# YouTubeStandalonePlayerActivity crashes as soon as it launches

Tags: android, youtube-api

In my Activity, I try to launch a particular video:

```
Intent intent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent(this, key, videoId);
startActivity(intent);
```

The video id is `LT5YThKAsic`, but right after the standalone player activity shows up (I can just briefly see my video there), I get a Force Close with the following stack trace which I don't think is all that helpful.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at com.google.android.youtube.core.utils.s.a(SourceFile:112)
    at com.google.android.youtube.core.async.GDataRequestFactory.a(SourceFile:395)
    at com.google.android.youtube.api.ab.a(SourceFile:141)
    at com.google.android.youtube.core.async.a.d.a(SourceFile:101)
    at com.google.android.youtube.core.async.a.d.a(SourceFile:73)
    at com.google.android.youtube.core.player.Director.v(SourceFile:530)
    at com.google.android.youtube.core.player.Director.a(SourceFile:398)
    at com.google.android.youtube.core.player.Director.a(SourceFile:412)
    at com.google.android.youtube.core.player.Director.a(SourceFile:425)
    at com.google.android.youtube.api.ApiPlayer.a(SourceFile:195)
    at com.google.android.youtube.api.service.a.d.run(SourceFile:167)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4134)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Force finishing activity com.google.android.youtube/.api.StandalonePlayerActivity
```

Any idea why it's crashing?

Comment: Kenny - what version of the YouTube app are you running and what is your device/OS version? We were unable to reproduce this behavior but will drill in some more.

Comment: @JarekWilkiewicz 4.4.11